# Insert data into hive table without delimiters

Tags: hive

I want 10 words in one column, another 10 words in another column .How to insert data into hive table with no specified delimiters using UDFs?

Comment: This does not seem reasonable. What is your motivation (A real life use-case)?

Comment: How would the elements not be delimited?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE employees_stg (emplid STRING, name STRING, age STRING, salary STRING, dept STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "(.{4})(.{35})(.{3})(.{11})(.{4})",     --Length of each column specified between braces "({})"
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s"     --Output in string format
     )
LOCATION '/path/to/input/employees_stg';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/sample_file.txt' INTO TABLE employees_stg;

SELECT * FROM employees_stg;